# Proving that a normal, abelian subgroup of G is in the center of G if |G/N| and |Aut(N)| are relatively prime.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I was trying to prove that a normal, abelian subgroup of $G$, $N$ is in the center of $G$ given that $|\operatorname{Aut}(N)|$ and $|G/N|$ are relatively prime.

The official question:

> *Let $N$ be an abelian normal subgroup of a finite group $G$. Assume  that the orders $|G/N|$ and $|\operatorname{Aut}(N)|$ are relatively prime. Prove that $N$ is contained in the center of $G$.*

My approach:

I considered the homomorphism:
$f:G \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ such that $f(g)(n) = gng^{-1}$.
This was given as a hint on the problem. So naturally, the first this I did was compute the kernel, and found the kernel to be $N$ since any element in $N$ maps to the identity automorphism since $N$ is abelian.

But I don't know how to use the fact that $\gcd(|G/N|, |\operatorname{Aut}(N)|) = 1$ since it is not necessarily true that $G/N$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ each have prime order.

Am I missing some trivial property about the kernel of this homomorphism that would enable me to say something about $N$ and or its relationship with $Z(G)$?

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: The order of any homomorphic image of G divides the order of G. What is the range of your homomorphism?

Comment: Please, look at my edit for hints on future questions or answers.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't aware of the styling standards! I'll be sure to keep them in mind for my future posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the first isomorphism theorem, $Im(f)\cong G/Ker(f)$. Now $N<Ker(f)$ since $N$ is abelian, so $|G/Ker(f)|=|Im(f)|$ is relatively prime to $|Aut(N)|$. But $Im(f)<Aut(N)$, so $|Im(f)|$ divides $|Aut(N)|$. Therefore the only possibility is that $Im(f)=\{e\}$, so that $Ker(f)=G$, i.e. $N$ is in the center.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a clarification: how do we know |G/Ker(f)| is relatively prime to |Aut(N)|?

Comment: Because since $N<Ker(f)$, $|G/Ker(f)|$ divides $|G/N|$ and we know that $|G/N|$ and $|Aut(N)|$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand it now. Thanks!