# Let $G$ a group finite and $N$ a normal subgroup, if $\text{gcd} (| \text{Aut} (N) |, | G |) = 1$, prove that $N \leq Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that the morphism that goes from $G$ to $\text{Aut} (N)$ is not injective, but I do not know how to use $\text{gcd} (| \text{Aut} (N) |, | G |) = 1$, since if it were any other value than $| G |$ it would be worth that the morphism of $G$ in $\text{Aut} (N)$ would not be injective.

Comment: Alsmost an [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765950/proving-that-a-normal-abelian-subgroup-of-g-is-in-the-center-of-g-if-g-n-and).

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\phi: G \to Aut(N)$ given by $\phi(g)(x)=g^{-1} x g$, which makes sense because $N$ is normal.

Let $m=|im(\phi)|$. Then $m$ divides both $|Aut(G)|$ and $|G|$ and so $m=1$. This means that $im(\phi)=\{id\}$, that is, $g^{-1} x g=x$ for all $g \in G$ and all $x \in N$, which is the same as $N < Z(G)$.

Comment: Can I try to supply some details:

I think $m$ divides $|G|$ by first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: For $m$ divide $|Aut(G)|$: Is it because $\phi$ is also a map from $G \to Aut(G)$, hence $im(\phi)$ is also a subgroup of $Aut(G)$ and hence $m$ divides $|Aut(G)|$.

Answer (score 2):

By N/C Lemma, $G/C_G(N)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(N)$. By Lagrange's Theorem, $|G/C_G(N)|$ divides, $|\text{Aut}(N)|$. Since $(|G|,|\text{Aut}(N)|)=1$, we have $G=C_G(N)$, which implies that $N\leq Z(G)$.